# Change a React Context state inside Axios instance

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I need to change the authenticated to false, when axios get a 401 from refresh endpoint. Heres the context, I need either call handleLogout or change authenticated to false

```
const Context = createContext();    
    function AuthProvider({ children }) {
            const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false);
            function handleLogout() {
                localStorage.removeItem('token');
                localStorage.removeItem('refreshToken');
                localStorage.removeItem('user');
                api.HEADER = undefined;
                setAuthenticated(false);
                return true;
            }
            return (
                <Context.Provider value={{ handleLogout }}>
                    {children}
                </Context.Provider>
            );
        }
    export { Context, AuthProvider};
```

heres the api instance

```
api.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    return response;
  },
  async function (error) {
    var originalRequest = error.config;
    const access_token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    if (error.response.status === 401 && access_token) {
      const response = await refreshToken(error).then((res)=>{
        if(res.status === 201){
          originalRequest.headers.Authorization = response.data.Token;
          return api(originalRequest);
        }
      }).catch((err)=>{
       // NEED TO CALL IT HERE
      });
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

However I'm having trouble to think a way to do this, because its a axios instance, not a react component.

Comment: So far the solution I found is using the api method inside the context itself, but it breaks my code organization...

Comment: Yes, that's not possible. You can for example create AxiosProvider component with access to proper context and configure axios there. Many libraries are based upon this concept of code organisation, for example restful-react